# WPF MenuItem style is not applied in TextBox context menu

Tags: wpf, xaml, textbox, menuitem, wpf-style

I once created a style to fix the bugged appearance of menu items in WPF. It's mainly about the menu text that is misaligned. It's too far in the top left corner and doesn't use proper spacing.

I discovered that it does work in window menus, but **not** in the context menu of `TextBox` which I tested now. So the question is, why isn't this style regarded for context menus from a text box?

**Update:** I found out that the `TextBox` uses its own menu item class, a private nested class `TextEditorContextMenu.EditorContextMenu` and its own menu items, the nested class `EditorMenuItem`. Both are derived from `ContextMenu` and `MenuItem`, resp. So if they are a subclass of the classes I have styled, then why isn't my style applied to them as well?

The only thing I could do was copying the definition of

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type MenuItem}, ResourceId=SubmenuItemTemplateKey}" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
```

from PresentationFramework.Aero's resources into my style file. But that very clearly makes my menus look like Windows 7 which may not be expected on Windows 8 or 10 (or XP). But redefining that style key at lest could influence the `EditorMenuItem`'s appearance. Why?

And if `EditorMenuItem` doesn't have its own style (I couldn't find it), why doesn't it use whatever style I provide for the base class as well? How does it know *not* to use my style but only the default one which is replaced and inaccessible for every other context menu?

Here's the XAML code, which is stored in MenuStyles.xaml and included in the `ResourceDictionary` from App.xaml.

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <!-- Expression Blend 4 created this (and a lot more) from some system theme on Windows 7 -->
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="Both"/>
        <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=SubmenuItemTemplateKey, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type MenuItem}}}"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Role" Value="TopLevelHeader">
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="7,2,8,3"/>
                <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=TopLevelHeaderTemplateKey, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type MenuItem}}}"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="Role" Value="TopLevelItem">
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="7,2,8,3"/>
                <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=TopLevelItemTemplateKey, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type MenuItem}}}"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="Role" Value="SubmenuHeader">
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5,4,2,3"/>
                <!-- Changed from 2,3,2,3 -->
                <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=SubmenuHeaderTemplateKey, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type MenuItem}}}"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="Role" Value="SubmenuItem">
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5,4,2,3"/>
                <!-- Changed from 2,3,2,3 -->
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

    <!-- Expression Blend 4 created this from some system theme on Windows 7 -->
    <!-- Edited like in: http://devlicio.us/blogs/christopher_bennage/archive/2008/06/19/styling-separators-in-wpf.aspx -->
    <!-- Decreased in height to be more platform standard -->
    <Style x:Key="{x:Static MenuItem.SeparatorStyleKey}" TargetType="{x:Type Separator}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Separator}">
                    <Grid Margin="0,3,0,2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <!-- Changed from 0,6,0,4 -->
                        <Rectangle Fill="#E0E0E0" Height="1" Margin="30,0,1,1"/>
                        <Rectangle Fill="White" Height="1" Margin="30,1,1,0"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the style manually by binding to the StaticResource-Style? You just have to give your style a key and then write sth like Style="{StaticResource MenuStyle}". I think it should work. There is also an "overwriteDefault"-Property in style i think.

Comment: I don't know what you mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem lies in not clearly understanding how styles in WPF work. There are two type of styles which handled differently.

The first type is theme style. Every `FrameworkElement` and `FrameworkContentElement` resolves its own `Style` using the `DefaultStyleKey` property when it's initialized. The location of resource dictionaries with theme resources is specified by `ThemeInfoAttribute`.

The second type is non-theme style. This style could be set explicitly by specifying the `Style` property of an element. Or it could also be resolved implicitly at initialization time. The `Setter`s of a non-theme style take precedence over `Setter`s of a theme style.

When you make an non-theme `Style` by adding it into the `ResourceDictionary` of an application or an element without a key, then it used implicitly and only instances of the target type without the explicitly set `Style` property will be affected and not derived types. This behavior is defined in the `FrameworkElement.GetRawValue` method ([line 1887](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/FrameworkElement.cs,1887)):

```cs
internal void GetRawValue(DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, ref EffectiveValueEntry entry)
{
    // ...

    if (dp != StyleProperty)
    {
        if (StyleHelper.GetValueFromStyleOrTemplate(new FrameworkObject(this, null), dp, ref entry))
        {
            return;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        object source;
        object implicitValue = FrameworkElement.FindImplicitStyleResource(this, this.GetType(), out source);
        if (implicitValue != DependencyProperty.UnsetValue)
        {
            // This style has been fetched from resources
            HasImplicitStyleFromResources = true;

            entry.BaseValueSourceInternal = BaseValueSourceInternal.ImplicitReference;
            entry.Value = implicitValue;
            return;
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

So your `Style` isn't applied because it's designed only for the `MenuItem` class because it's not a theme `Style`. And you have two ways to change the `Style` of items in the `TextBox`'s `ContextMenu` and they both have cons.

The first way is to add a `Style` for all `TextBox`es and set in it your `ContextMenu`. But you will loose reconversion and speller `MenuItems` if Text Services Framework and spell check are used, respectively.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.Copy" />
                <MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.Cut" />
                <MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.Paste" />
            </ContextMenu>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And the second way is to use reflection at startup to create a `Style` for the `TextEditorContextMenu.EditorMenuItem` class. But this method should be used only if you are using spell checking and Text Services Framework.

```cs
// Inside the Application.OnStartup method
Style menuItemStyle = TryFindResource(typeof(MenuItem)) as Style;
if (menuItemStyle != null)
{
    Assembly menuItemAssembly = typeof(MenuItem).Assembly;
    Type editorMenuType = menuItemAssembly.GetType("System.Windows.Documents.TextEditorContextMenu+EditorMenuItem", false);
    if (editorMenuType != null)
    {
        Resources.Add(editorMenuType, menuItemStyle);
    }

    Type reconversionMenuType = menuItemAssembly.GetType("System.Windows.Documents.TextEditorContextMenu+ReconversionMenuItem", false);
    if (reconversionMenuType != null)
    {
        Resources.Add(reconversionMenuType, menuItemStyle);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I've already seen the first bit of code but it's also bad for non-English environments because you need to use the localised menu texts. (Well, the text is actually missing here, does that mean it's localised automagically?) The last bit of code actually solved my problem now. BTW, what is that "reconversion" thing in the menu? I've seen it browsing the framework code but couldn't find out what it does.

Comment: Yes, they will be automatically localized because the `MenuItem` class uses the `RoutedUICommand.Text` property if the `Header` property isn't set. To understand what is reconversion read [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374119(v=vs.85).aspx) and remarks [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms538970(v=vs.85).aspx).